# How to delete Material UI chip element based on Material UI's github label picker example

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I was playing with Material UI autocomplete component's github label picker example and modified it as per sandbox below:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-hwi3l?file=/demo.js

The Autocomplete works fine. When I select company names from the list they show up as chip elements after closing and when I deselect them individually, they get hidden as well. However, I am unable to figure out how to delete individual elements by clicking on chip's close button. I am unable to figure out what exactly to put in the chip's onDelete prop?

```
 {
          value.map((company, index) => (
            <Chip
              label={company.name}
              onDelete={(event, newValue) => {
                //setPendingValue(company);
              }}
              color="primary"
              className={classes.selectedCompanies}
            />
          ))
        }
```

Since the Chip as per sandbox is inside the value array, I am not sure how I could delete something from inside it while looping through it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to delete from an array is to filter where each iterated item is not the deletable item. Doing so returns a new array that omits the deletable item. So in your example:

The delete-handler:

```
const handleDelete = name => {
  const newValue = value.filter(company => company.name !== name);
  setValue(newValue);
};
```

The chip element:

```
{value.map((company) => (
  <Chip
    key={company.name}
    label={company.name}
    onDelete={() => handleDelete(company.name)}
```

[The codesandbox with the solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-qlykf?file=/demo.js)

Note, in React, you should [include the iterated key in each list item](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Comment: Thank you so much!